# How to get the 3rd column in an array by using 1st and 2nd column values as index in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array with three columns like this:

```
 A       B      C
 10      75     20 
 30      67     50 
 85      12     30
 98      49     70
```

I have A and B values, and I want to get the corresponding C value.
For example if I enter (30,67) it should display 50.
Does Matlab have any trick for getting C value?
(my dataset is very large, and I need a fast way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your input data be defined as

```
data   = [ 10      75     20 
           30      67     50 
           85      12     30
           98      49     70];
values = [ 30      67];
```

This should be pretty fast:

```
index = data(:,1)==values(1) & data(:,2)==values(2); %//  logical index to matching rows
result = data(index,3); %// third-column value for those rows
```

This gives **all** third-column values that match, should there be more than one.

---

If you want to specify **several pairs of values at once**, and obtain all matching results:

```
index = any(bsxfun(@eq, data(:,1).', values(:,1)), 1) & ...
        any(bsxfun(@eq, data(:,2).', values(:,2)), 1);
result = data(index,3);
```

For example, given

```
data   = [ 10      75     20 
           30      67     50 
           85      12     30
           98      49     70
           30      67     80 ];
values = [ 30      67
           98      49];
```

the result would be

```
result =
    50
    70
    80
```

Comment: and what if there is more than a single pair in `values`?

Comment: @Shai The question doesn't say that. It's not even clear how the output should be arrranged in that case. But it's an interesting generalization; I've edited my answer to include that

Comment: I realized this approach is very faster than @Shai approach, am i right?

Answer (score 4):

you can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
ABC = [10      75     20 
       30      67     50 
       85      12     30
       98      49     70];
q = [30 67
     85 12];
[~, locb] = ismember( q, ABC(:,1:2), 'rows' );
C = ABC(locb,3);
```

The result you get is

```
C =
50
30
```

Note that the code assume all pairs in `q` can be found in `ABC`.

Comment: Last line could easily be made more robust `C=nan(size(locb)); C(Lia)=ABC(locb(Lia),3);`. then `nan` is returned for all pairs which are not found.

Comment: @Daniel you can also use `Lia` - the first returned value of `ismember` instead of `locb>0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sparse matrix. This solution only works if C does not contain any zeros and A and B are integers larger 0

```
A = [10 30 85 98]';
B = [75 67 12 49]';
C = [20 50 30 70]';
S = sparse(A,B,C);
S(10,75) % returns corresponding C-Value if found, 0 otherwise.
```

Comment: will only work also when there are no repetitions in `A` and `B`, otherwise `S(a,b)` will have the *sum* of the `C` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try `accumarray`:

```
YourMatrix = accumarray([A B],C,[],@mean,true);
```

This way `YourMatrix` will be a matrix of size `[max(A) max(B)]`, with the values of `C` at `YourMatrix(A(ind),B(ind))`, with `ind` the desired index of `A` and `B`:

```
A = [10 30 85 98]';
B = [75 67 12 49]';
C = [20 50 30 70]';
YourMatrix = accumarray([A B],C,[],@mean,true);
ind = 2;
YourMatrix(A(ind),B(ind))
ans =
   50
```

This way, when there is a repetition in `A B`, it will return the corresponding `C` value, provided each unique pair of `A B` has the same `C` value. The `true` flag makes `accumarray` output a sparse matrix as opposed to a full matrix.

Comment: `sparse` should work better here, see [Daniel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32177173/1714410)'s answer.

Comment: True. I prefer accumarray because it offers more options, such as when A and B contain a repetition, you can use @mean.

Comment: This solution creates a matrix of size `[max(A),max(B)]`, it can easily run out of memory.

Comment: As does the try with sparse, though that will be a sparse matrix. I updated to include the 'true' flag to output a sparse matrix.